# Why does GitHub Page with custom domain shows blank index page?

Tags: github, dns, jekyll

http://harryherskowitz.com/

Sometimes my page loads correctly, sometimes I get a blank "Index of /" page.
When I test on multiple devices some will work then others wont then they flip flop.

What could be going wrong? I have Anames set to the correct IPs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

There seems to be issues with your DNS config for your domain:

[image]

Your `A` records should point to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154` as defined in the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider).

`192.241.148.82` seems to be your old host.

---

It looks like you've just published the website. It can take several hours for the DNS to propagate everywhere. You're likely still getting the old place the website was pointing to before you had it on GitHub. Just give it time and it will resolve itself.

[image]

> [DNS Propagation - Explained](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9622/10/dns-propagation--explained)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah I just did all this today. I'll give it some time.

Comment: I'm still having the problem. Could DNS be taking this long (2+ days) to propagate?

Comment: @Harry See my updated answer. It seems you have problems with your DNS setup which is still pointing to your old hosting provider

Comment: I see. Do I need to delete the old Aname? I have 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154 added.

Comment: Yes, you do need to delete the old one. That's what's causing you to get the old site sometimes

Comment: Awesome seems to be working now. Thanks again really appreciate it.